# verified my free account with CC, still Can't use sendgrid. Phone number not supported

Tags: heroku, verification

I've verified my account with CC and got a couple of addons, when I wanted to create sendgrid, it said I needed to verify my phone number, but my country isn't supported. My account is verified with CC! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to contact Sendgrid support (they offer limited free support).  Because of spammers, their identity requirements are a little stronger than your average web service.  1st thing to check is that your country is supported by their platform though.

Comment: Thanks, apparently enabling 2FA with google authenticator fixed the problem. Love you.